# Adding class for select box inside javascript

Tags: javascript

so I found a code that I would like to use on my form to select an option when clicking an a div.

```
$("div").on("click", function(e) {
    var $select = $("select");
    $select.val($(this).data("value"));

    // simulate click:
    $select.find(":selected").click();
});
```

But i have more than one select box in my form. Is there a way to get a class from my select box to this code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "get a class from my select box", but essentially as with *any* selector you need to identify in some way the HTML element(s) you want to target.  Maybe you can uniquely identify it in the entire page?  Maybe you can traverse the DOM from the clicked element to identify it?  We can't know without seeing the HTML of course.  But basically you just need to specify with the *vast* number of options available to you which element you're targeting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If the class is "my-class", just do

```
var $select = $("select.my-class");
```

jQuery works on CSS selectors, so if you can target an element with a CSS selector you can use the same in your jQuery code.